# How to Insert several separate characters in a sqlite3 cell?

Tags: python, sql, database, sqlite, row

I want to insert `several` different values ​​in just `one cell`

***E.g.***

```
Friends' names
  ID  | Grade        | Names
  ----+--------------+----------------------------
  1   | elementary   | Kai, Matthew, Grace
  2   | guidance     | Eli, Zoey, David, Nora, William
  3   | High school  | Emma, James, Levi, Sophia
```

***Or as a list or dictionary:***

```
  ID  | Grade        | Names
  ----+--------------+------------------------------
  1   | elementary   | [Kai, Matthew, Grace]
  2   | guidance     | [Eli, Zoey, David, Nora, William]
  3   | High school  | [Emma, James, Levi, Sophia]
```

or

```
  ID  | Grade        | Names
  ----+--------------+---------------------------------------------
  1   | elementary   | { a:Kai, b:Matthew, c:Grace}
  2   | guidance     | { a:Eli, b:Zoey, c:David, d:Nora, e:William}
  3   | High school  | { a:Emma, b:James, c:Levi, d:Sophia}
```

**`Is there a way?`**

Comment: SQLite core has no tools to analyze/compose a string from/to a collection. You can install the JSON1 extention to enable compose/analyse JSON-formatted strings.

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is a way, but that doesn't mean you should do it this way.

You could for example save your values as a json string and save them inside the column. If you later want to add a value you can simply parse the json, add the value and put it back into the database. (Might also work with a BLOB, but I'm not sure)

**However**, I would not recommend saving a list inside of a column, as SQL is not meant to be used like that.

What I would recommend is that you have a table and for every grade with its own primary key. Like this:

| ID | Grade |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Elementary |
| 2 | Guidance |
| 3 | High school |

And then another table containing all the names, having its own primary key and the gradeId as its secondary key. E.g:

| ID | GradeID | Name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | Kai |
| 2 | 1 | Matthew |
| 3 | 1 | Grace |
| 4 | 2 | Eli |
| 5 | 2 | Zoey |
| 6 | 2 | David |
| 7 | 2 | Nora |
| 8 | 2 | William |
| 9 | 3 | Emma |
| 10 | 3 | James |
| 11 | 3 | Levia |
| 12 | 3 | Sophia |

If you want to know more about this, you should read about Normalization in SQL.